# Resolving Dependancy Conflicts in Rust

Tags: rust

I am working on some library code that will be used in a bigger project/workspace. I can run the unit tests for my code when is not within the bigger project's sub directory. However, when I try and put my code into the larger project and build it, it will fail.

I've tried cleaning, adding my code's path to 'members' in the workspace's cargo.toml and reading:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html

**My code's cargo.toml** (Note: problem still exists w/o tokio and hex):

```
[package]
name = "zero-knowledge"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [""]
description = "Zero Knowledge Proof Generation and Verification using STARKs"
repository = "https://github.com/libra/libra"
homepage = "https://libra.org"
license = "Apache-2.0"
publish = false
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
project-root = "0.2.2"
web3 = "0.15.0"
ethereum_abi = "0.3.0"
hex = "0.4.3"

[dev-dependencies]
tokio = { version = "0.2.22", features = ["full"] }
```

**Workspace Cargo.toml**:

```
[workspace]

members = [
    "client/faucet",
    "client/json-rpc",
    "client/libra-dev",
    ...
    "ol/zero_knowledge",
]

# NOTE: default-members is the complete list of binaries that form the "production Libra codebase". These members should
# never include crates that require fuzzing features or test features. These are the crates we want built with no extra
# test-only code included.
#
# For more, see the "Conditional compilation for tests" section in documentation/coding_guidelines.md.
default-members = [
    "common/trace",
    "config/generate-key",
    ...
]

[profile.bench]
debug = true

# //////// 0L ////////
[profile.release]
opt-level = 'z'     # Optimize for size.
lto = true          # Enable Link Time Optimization
codegen-units = 1   # Reduce number of codegen units to increase optimizations.
panic = 'abort'     # Abort on panic
```

**Output from building**:

```
Updating crates.io index
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.24
   ...
   Compiling enum_dispatch v0.3.3
   error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `export` in `syn`
  --> /.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/enum_dispatch-0.3.3/src/enum_dispatch_item.rs:56:11
   |
56 | impl syn::export::quote::ToTokens for EnumDispatchItem {
   |           ^^^^^^ could not find `export` in `syn`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `export` in `syn`
  --> /.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/enum_dispatch-0.3.3/src/enum_dispatch_variant.rs:47:11
   |
47 | impl syn::export::quote::ToTokens for EnumDispatchVariant {
   |           ^^^^^^ could not find `export` in `syn`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `export` in `syn`
   --> /.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/enum_dispatch-0.3.3/src/expansion.rs:303:26
    |
303 |             syn::export::Span::call_site(),
    |                          ^^^^ not found in `syn::export`
    |
help: consider importing one of these items
    |
3   | use crate::expansion::proc_macro::Span;
    |
3   | use crate::expansion::proc_macro::bridge::server::Span;
    |
3   | use proc_macro2::Span;
    |
3   | use proc_macro::Span;
    |
      and 3 other candidates

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
error: could not compile `enum_dispatch`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Let me know if you need any additional information and thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `syn` crate made a breaking change in version `1.0.58`, when it renamed a module that was not meant to be used by other crates. The `enum_dispatch` crate was one that erroneously was using this module and thus was broken but later fixed in version `0.3.5` (see the relevant [issue](https://gitlab.com/antonok/enum_dispatch/-/issues/37)).

I don't know where exactly in your dependency tree `syn` and `enum_dispatch` sit, but I recommend updating `enum_dispatch` to a newer version.